# Stuck on hard Kakuro

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, grid-deduction

I‘m stuck on this Kakuro. Does anyone have any hints how to proceed? Thanks!

[image: Hard Kakuro]

Answer (score 5):

Besides the fact that there probably is an error in the top half...

> - The 2nd row from the bottom, sum 39, has 3 cells that can ony be 7,8,9.
>  you can strike out all other 7,8,9 (red).
>  - The column with sum 13 at the bottom cannot have 7 on top, so it cannot have 6 in the bottom row.
>  So the bottom row, sum 30 has 8,9 in the center, 7,6 at the ends (blue).
>  - This places the 7 in the 2nd-from-bottom row, sum 39 (green).
>
>  [image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 4):

At first glance:

> You have an error somewhere. :-(

Because:

> Look at the 44 in the 2nd column.
>  - The middle four numbers (green box) must be 6,7,8,9 in some order.
>  - So those numbers cannot appear elsewhere in the 44 (green strikethrough).
>  - Now the 12 in the 2nd row must be 8,4 or 9,3 (orange strikethrough).
>  - And the 11 in the 1st column must be 2,9 or 3,8 (orange strikethrough).
>  - But now there is no valid solution for the 9 in the 1st row.
>  - So there must be an error in the candidate numbers in this area.
>  [image: Partially completed Kakuro with conflict highlighted]

Comment: Agreed. There are other options for the 14 in the fifth column.